# mod-rewrite with 4 variables and exclusion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to map the following URL pattern:
/A/B/C-D/E/
to following script:
A-B.php?C=D

And it should not be performed on URLs starting with following:
images
files

I have used following rules however those are not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+) 
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:Files|images)/)(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)/(.*)/?$ $1-$2.php?$3=$4 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `http://domain.com/something/A/B/C-D/E/` will match ? Where `something` can be anything except `files` or `images` ?

Comment: A sample is http://domain.com/A/B/C-D/E/ will be matched where A is anything except files or images and it will be redirected to a page like this: http://domain.com/news-view.php?NewsID=100 @JustinIurman

Comment: And what about the `E` ? Ignored ?

Comment: @JustinIurman yes. E is there only for SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax errors.

Following your style, you can have it this way

```
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:files|images)/)[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ /$1-$2.php?$3=$4 [NC,L]
```

You can also have the same with this (to alleviate the rule)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:files|images)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ /$1-$2.php?$3=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Both are working, however a little description is highly appreciated so to know what was the issue.

Comment: The problem was located at your use of negative lookahead `?!` (you can compare yours to mine and you'll see the syntax difference)